# Präposition mit "glücklich sein"

Tags: preposition

Welche der beiden Möglichkeiten ist richtig?

> Jemand ist *glücklich **auf*** etwas.
>   Jemand ist *glücklich **von*** etwas.

Ich finde generell, dass es schwer ist, die richtige Präposition zu nutzen. Habt ihr Tipps?

Comment: Man kann auf jeden Fall glücklich _über_ etwas sein. Andere Präpositionen wären denkbar, aber es kommt wie so oft auf den (nicht gegebenen) Kontext an.

Comment: "Susi ist glücklich auf Hiddensee" ginge, "Susi ist glücklich von der Pest geheilt worden zu sein." auch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beide Varianten sind zumindest unüblich. Ich vermute sogar, dass man sie als falsch ansehen könnte.

Folgendes ist möglich:

> Roland ist *glücklich **wegen*** der bestandenen Prüfung.

Roland hat eine Prüfung erfolgreich absolviert. Deswegen ist er jetzt glücklich.

---

> Johanna ist *glücklich **über*** ihren neuen Arbeitsplatz.

Johanna hat einen neuen Arbeitsplatz gefunden. Darüber ist die jetzt glücklich.

Comment: Doch, *glücklich von* ginge, wenn es sich bei der Glücksursache um ein Rauschgift handelt. *Eh Alter, bin voll glücklich von dem Zeug!*. Achtung: dieser Kommentar ist nicht ernst gemeint.

Answer (score 0):

Ich bin glücklich mit meiner Partnerin.

Ich bin glücklich in meinem Beruf.

Ich bin glücklich über die bestandene Prüfung.

Ich bin glücklich aus der Sache herausgekommen.

Comment: Deine Antwort wäre hilfreicher, wenn Du eine kurze Erklärung zu jedem Beispielsatz hinzufügen könntest.